# Android shell script

Tags: android, shell

I have an android 4.2 phone on which I wish to run the following script:

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

If I put it into and .sh file, and have the SManager app to run it, it does nothing, no error nothing, just get back the console. I allow root access for the app.

If I manually type it into Terminal Emulator, then it works.

How can I run .sh files easily (without much typing) other then SManager, as its obviously not working.

Thank you

Comment: how are you running it? `sh your_script.sh` should make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my scripts was ctrl c ctrl v to sh files.
Some windows spec char went into the script, and it did nothing.
As soon as i typed the whole thing in on touchkeyboard,
AND allowed Root run within SManager (it was not enough to start it as rooted only),
it came alive.

Thanks!